# При удалении из массива всегда удаляется последний элемент

Tags: vue.js

Vue.js удаление элемента из массива.

При выполнении функции всегда удаляется последний элемент

```js
   
   
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data:{
                openForm: 1,
                newTodoText:'',
                nextTodoId: 0,
                infoUser:{
                    email:'',
                    firstName:'',
                    secondName:'',
                    phone:''
                },
                nameGuest: 50,
                guests:[]
            },

            methods:{
                toogleShow(){
                    this.openForm = !this.openForm;
                },

                addNewGuests: function () {
                    this.guests.push({
                        id: this.nextTodoId++,
                        nameG: this.newTodoText
                    })
                },

             
            },
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <div class="container" id="app">
        <div class="row" v-show="openForm">
            <div class="col-6 offset-3"><br><br>
                <form class = "d-flex flex-column w-100">
                    <label>
                        Email <br>
                        <input 
                            type="email" 
                            v-model="infoUser.email" 
                            class = "w-100"
                        >
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        First name <br>
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            v-model="infoUser.firstName" 
                            class = "w-100"
                        >
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Second name <br>
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            v-model="infoUser.secondName" 
                            class = "w-100"
                        >
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Phone <br>
                        <input 
                            type="phone" 
                            v-model="infoUser.phone" 
                            class = "w-100"
                        >
                    </label>
                    <hr class = "w-100">

                    <div class="w-100">
                        Guest 
                        <button 
                            class="btn btn-primary" 
                            @click.prevent="addNewGuests"
                        >
                        +
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <template 
                        v-for="(n, index) in guests" 
                    >
                        <div                  
                            @dblclick="guests.splice(index, 1)"
                            v-bind:key="guests.id"
                        >
                            Guest {{++index}} 
                            <br>
                            <input 
                                type="text" 
                                class = "w-100" 
                                
                            >
                        </div>
                    </template>

                    <hr class="w-100">
                    <button 
                        class = "btn btn-success" 
                        @click.prevent="toogleShow"
                    >
                    Send form
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" v-show="!openForm">
            <div class="col-3 offset-3">
                <table class="table table-borderd fluid">
                    <tr 
                        v-for="(value, key) in infoUser"
                    >
                        <td>{{key}}</td>
                        <td>{{value}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- <tr>
                        <td>guests</td>
                        <td 
                            v-for="item in guests"
                        >
                        <td>{{item}}</td>
                        </td>  -->
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
   
   
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data:{
                openForm: 1,
                newTodoText:'',
                nextTodoId: 0,
                infoUser:{
                    email:'',
                    firstName:'',
                    secondName:'',
                    phone:''
                },
                nameGuest: 50,
                guests:[]
            },

            methods:{
                toogleShow(){
                    this.openForm = !this.openForm;
                },

                addNewGuests: function () {
                    this.guests.push({
                        id: this.nextTodoId++,
                        nameG: this.newTodoText,
                        value: "",
                    })
                },

             
            },
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <div class="container" id="app">
        <div class="row" v-show="openForm">
            <div class="col-6 offset-3"><br><br>
                <form class = "d-flex flex-column w-100">
                    <label>
                        Email <br>
                        <input 
                            type="email" 
                            v-model="infoUser.email" 
                            class = "w-100"
                        >
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        First name <br>
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            v-model="infoUser.firstName" 
                            class = "w-100"
                        >
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Second name <br>
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            v-model="infoUser.secondName" 
                            class = "w-100"
                        >
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Phone <br>
                        <input 
                            type="phone" 
                            v-model="infoUser.phone" 
                            class = "w-100"
                        >
                    </label>
                    <hr class = "w-100">

                    <div class="w-100">
                        Guest 
                        <button 
                            class="btn btn-primary" 
                            @click.prevent="addNewGuests"
                        >
                        +
                        </button>
                    </div>

   
                        <div   
           v-for="(n, index) in guests"
                            @dblclick="guests.splice(index, 1)"
                            v-bind:key="n.id"
                        >
                            Guest {{index+1}} 
                            <br>
                            <input 
                                type="text" 
                                class = "w-100" 
                                v-model="n.value"
                                
                            >
                        </div>
   
                    <hr class="w-100">
                    <button 
                        class = "btn btn-success" 
                        @click.prevent="toogleShow"
                    >
                    Send form
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" v-show="!openForm">
            <div class="col-3 offset-3">
                <table class="table table-borderd fluid">
                    <tr 
                        v-for="(value, key) in infoUser"
                    >
                        <td>{{key}}</td>
                        <td>{{value}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- <tr>
                        <td>guests</td>
                        <td 
                            v-for="item in guests"
                        >
                        <td>{{item}}</td>
                        </td>  -->
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Увы я уже реализовал вывод информации в массив. Проблема сама в удалении по двойному коику на созданный DOM узел, за него отвечает функция splice. Вот в  ней самой проблема.

Comment: вы вообще, код тестировали? По каким признакам Вы определяете, что удаляется последний?

Comment: Ну вот добавьте 5 елементов к примеру, и дважды нажмите на него, удаляет последний, вне зависимости на нажатый :( я уже тестировал и рефокторинг сделал. Осталось только разобраться с удалением елементов. :((9 Не кусайтесь. Я только вошёл во Vue

Comment: Другими словами Вы смотрите на цифру возле надписи Guest..... Однако, это просто индекс массива, а не id гостя... так у Вас реализована логика вывода информации... однако, я сделал так, чтобы  удалялся именно тот гость, на котором был клик - это можно проверить, если заполнить все инпуты

Comment: Всё всё))) Я не то тестировал. Увы пока что слабо разобрался как оно удаляет. Моя ошибка в том что у меня была переписана переменная ++index. Когда написал index+1 как у вас в варианте - всё заработало как надо. Большое спасибо молодой человек))